# Is there a comprehensive guide for Weblogic Scripting Tool (WLST)

Tags: xml, wlst

I'm unsuccessfully using WLST to modify a jmsmodule.xml file online. I have to achieve this programatically rather than using the Weblogic Console. However, I've "recorded" the commands while in the console. However the recorded commands when put into the online python WLST script don't work. These are the commands that fail:

```
cmo.setPriority(-1)
cmo.setDeliveryMode('Persistent')
cmo.setTimeToDeliver('-1')
cmo.setTimeToLive(-1)
```

The error that gets spit out is: AttributeError: setPriority

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

cmo refers to the object you're currently in. Be sure that you navigate to the correct MBean using cd() commands

Answer (score 2):

Better you first check the MBean containing attributes with ls() in interactive mode.
For clear idea you watch the following youtube video by Jeffrey where you can record the script and updating for further use made easy...

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=luhBaviP2uM[enter link description here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=luhBaviP2uM)